# Why am I getting an undefined error in a for loop when I can see the value in the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function here as part of a vue.js project.  I'm trying to find all versions that start with 'iPad' and move them to the end of the array.

I am taking an existing array `this.jobs` and sorting the array using another method `sortVersions`

```
orderedReleases: function() {
  let newlist = this.jobs.sort(sortVersions)
  for (let i in newlist) {
    console.log(newlist[i].version)
    // logs all the versions as expected
    if (newlist[i].version.startsWith("iPad")) {
      // returns error Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
      newlist.push(newlist.splice(i, 1))
    }
  }
  return newlist;
},
```

When I call this function I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
```

But as you can see in the code, `console.log(newlist[i].version)` shows me all the versions.

What am I doing wrong?

console.log(newlist[i].version) output

```
2.5.1
2.5.0
2.4.1
2.3.0
2.2.1
2.1.3
```

Comment: It would help if we could see an example of the `this.jobs` and `sortVersions`

Comment: may be some of property (newlist array) dont have version

Comment: Please show us what the console logs with `newlist[i].version`. Since it is returning all versions, as you claim, this is most likely an array and not a string. Hence `startsWith` will not work.

Comment: Can you post the log output of console.log(newlist[i].version) by running debug?

Comment: Could you give more of your code? For example where the array is declared and where values are assigned?

Comment: @icecub the console log shows clean versions

Comment: @icecub if the console returns clean versions that would make each a string right?  i updated the op

Comment: Please include an [mcve]. You can replace your own `this.jobs` with a **minimal** hard-coded version that does reproduce the issue, so that we can make it fail too. e.g `let newlist = [{version: "2.5.1"}, {version: "foo-bar"}]`. For debugging purpose you may want to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(newlist))` from your own page and check it's indeed correct.